# Can anyone check this SImple chatbot application and suggest me the corrective measures?

Tags: python

This chatbot will take the input from csv file and give the output to the user's question...here problem I am facing is when user asks any question, it gives tkenize output of user's text

```
#Block 1
""" In this block we will import all the required libraries  """
import pandas as pd                      # importing pandas to read the csv file
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import random
import string
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity


#Block 2
"""  This block will import csv file and save it to a variable   """

db_main = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Python\QnA_using_NLTK\qa_database.csv', sep = ',',
                       names=["Question", "Answer", "user_response"])


# Block 3
""" Data Cleaning and preprocessing  """
#nltk.download('stopwords')  

corpus = []             # corpus list is created to append output of initial cleaning of data 
wordnet=WordNetLemmatizer()
for i in range(0, len(db_main)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', db_main['Question'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [wordnet.lemmatize(word) for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)


#sent_tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(db_main.Question)# converts to list of sentences 
#word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(db_main.Question)# converts to list of words

#Block 4

""" This block will create tfidf vector and will create bag of words  """

# Creating the Bag of Words model
cv = TfidfVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

#Block 5
""" This block will define 2 functions"""

lemmer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def LemTokens(tokens):
    return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)
def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))

#Block 6
""" this block will listdown user inputs and probable outputs  """

GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up","hey",)
GREETING_RESPONSES = ["hi", "hey", "*nods*", "hi there", "hello", "I am glad! You are talking to me"]
```

#Block 7

```
"""Checking for greetings """

def greeting(sentence):
    """If user's input is a greeting, return a greeting response"""
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
            return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)




# Block 8
""" Generating response """
def response(user_response):
    robo_response=''
    corpus.append(user_response)
    TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemNormalize, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform(corpus)
    vals = cosine_similarity(tfidf[-1], tfidf)
    idx=vals.argsort()[0][-2]
    flat = vals.flatten()
    flat.sort()
    req_tfidf = flat[-2]
    if(req_tfidf==0):
        robo_response=robo_response+"I am sorry! I don't understand you"
        return robo_response
    else:
        robo_response = robo_response+corpus[idx]
        return robo_response


flag=True
print("ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!")

while(flag==True):
    user_response = input()
    user_response=user_response.lower()
    if(user_response!='bye'):
        if(user_response=='thanks' or user_response=='thank you' ):
            flag=False
            print("ROBO: You are welcome..")
        else:
            if(greeting(user_response)!=None):
                print("ROBO: "+greeting(user_response))
            else:
                print("ROBO: ",end="")
                print(response(user_response))
                corpus.remove(user_response)
    else:
        flag=False
        print("ROBO: Bye! take care..")
```

Comment: Please only provide working code, which your require to get reviewed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this post is off-topic for this site. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - note that it states "_If you are looking for feedback on a specific **working** piece of code...then you are in the right place!_" Also, when posting your question, there should have been text on the side that read "_Your question **must contain code that is already working correctly**_..." When you have fixed the code, please [edit] your post to include the working code and it can be reviewed."

Answer (score 1):

okay... 
just have some advice for you
First of all - read PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
It's a really important document for writing clear code in Python
Try to make a clear structure of your code - check all imports and def's
You do not really need to import all module for using only one function of it - like pandas
Also, check all spaces and brackets in your code
So, you better should not use "magic strings" - try to use some variables for filename and columns in it, and then you will be able to move them away from code
And use a construction like
    if **name** == "**main**":

try to refactor your code and then someone will help you with review

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.